# Riemann-Stieltjes integral involving a floor function

Tags: analysis

$g(x) = 2sinx - Floor(2sinx)$, $x$ belongs to $R$. 
What are the discontinuity points of g on the interval [0, pi] and what are the values $g(c+)$ and $g(c-)$?

I tried graphing on wolfram, but it said the function is continuous, so I am unsure of what the discontinuous points are. However, based on the graph I have it looks like they would be around 0, .6, and 2.6, and pi perhaps?

The second part asks to compute the Riemann-Stieltjes integral from $0$ to $\pi$ of $cos(x)dg(x)$.  Does anyone know a useful formula for this part? Is there one specifically for integral a dealing with pi/polar coordinates or do you still use integers? Thanks in advance!  Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Did you mean $g(x)=2\sin x-\lfloor2\sin x\rfloor$? Where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integer part of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

**For part 1:**

Assuming $g(x)=2\sin x-\lfloor2\sin x\rfloor$ it follows $g$ is discontinuous where $\lfloor2\sin x\rfloor$ is discontinuous. Then, for $x\in[0,\pi]$, $g$ is discontinuous for $\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{6}$. Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi/6^-}{g(x)}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi/6^-}{(2\sin x-\lfloor2\sin x\rfloor)}\\
&=2\sin(\pi/6)-\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi/6^-}{\lfloor2\sin x\rfloor}\\
&=2(1/2)-0\;\;\;\quad\quad\quad\text{because $0<2\sin x<1$ as $x\rightarrow\pi/6^-$}\\
&=1\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi/6^+}{g(x)}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi/6^+}{(2\sin x-\lfloor2\sin x\rfloor)}\\
&=2\sin(\pi/6)-\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi/6^+}{\lfloor2\sin x\rfloor}\\
&=2(1/2)-1\;\;\;\quad\quad\quad\text{because $1<2\sin x<2$ as $x\rightarrow\pi/6^+$}\\
&=0\\
\end{align}
In a similar way we have $g(\frac{\pi}{2}^-)=g(\frac{\pi}{2}^+)=1$ and $g(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$; and $g(\frac{5\pi}{6}^-)=0$ and $g(\frac{5\pi}{6}^+)=1$.